# SSH 2FA authentification

Tags: ssh, google-2fa

I'm trying to enable 2fA authentification on my lighsail server, running ubuntu 20.04.
I installed google-authenticator and launched it, configured /etc/pam.d/sshd to add the following line :

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
auth required pam_permit.so
```

and then /etc/ssh/sshd_config to set :

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

But then nothing happens. If I add the line :

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

Then the ssh client asks for a password that I don't have (I have a keypair, but no password).
What can I do to enable 2FA ?

Comment: Did you restart sshd after making changes?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Put `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam` to `sshd_config`